# Questions regarding numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a program using normal Python, and I now think it would be a lot better to use numpy instead of standard lists. The problem is there are a number of things where I'm confused how to use numpy, or whether I can use it at all.

1. In general how do np.arrays work? Are they dynamic in size like a C++ vector or do I have declare their length and type beforehand like a standard C++ array? In my program I've got a lot of cases where I create a list
   `ex_list = []` and then cycle through something and append to it `ex_list.append(some_lst)`. Can I do something like with a numpy array? What if I knew the size of `ex_list`, could I declare and empty one and then add to it?

If I can't, let's say I only call this list, would it be worth it to convert it to numpy afterwards, i.e. is calling a numpy list faster?

2. Can I do more complicated operations for each element using a numpy array (not just adding 5 to each etc), example below.

   `full_pallete = [(int(1+i*(255/127.5)),0,0) for i in range(0,128)]`

   `full_pallete += [col for col in right_palette if col[1]!=0 or col[2]!=0 or col==(0,0,0)]`

In other words, does it make sense to convert to a numpy array and then cycle through it using something other than for loop?

Answer (score 1):

1. Numpy arrays can be appended to (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), although in general calling the `append` function many times in a loop has a heavy performance cost - it is generally better to pre-allocate a large array and then fill it as necessary. This is because the arrays themselves do have fixed size under the hood, but this is hidden from you in python.
2. Yes, Numpy is well designed for many operations similar to these. In general, however, you don't want to be looping through numpy arrays (or arrays in general in python) if they are very large. By using inbuilt numpy functions, you basically make use of all sorts of compiled speed up benefits. As an example, rather than looping through and checking each element for a condition, you would use `numpy.where()`.

The real reason to use numpy is to benefit from pre-compiled mathematical functions and data processing utilities on large arrays - both those in the core numpy library as well as many other packages that use them.

Comment: So what would be an alternative to looping through an array with a for loop, if it's a numpy array? Of course I don't want to loop through large arrays. But in my case I HAVE to loop through some very large arrays and change the values inside of them.

Comment: Find the appropriate numpy function for the problem you are trying to solve. Although you can loop through them if you want - you just won't benefit from the performance increase. The docs are pretty good for all of this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html. What do you want to do in particular?

Comment: So would the most efficient way of pre-allocating an np.array `ex_arr = np.zeros((size1,size2),int)` (i want int)

Comment: You need to look at your algorithm and find the upper bound for what `int` will need to be. This is entirely problem dependent.

Comment: The most complex part is: I'm cycling row by row `r` through a matrix `M`, for each value in the row `r[i]` I'm using it to identify another value from another array `get_val[r[i]]`. Then I use a hash table to get a new value for `r[i] = hash_table[get_val[r[i]]]`

Comment: Regarding int: Well of course... I'm confident I won't be having any sort overflow problems. Really the size of the rows aren't that much of a problem, I just have multiple matrices each with a bunch of rows.

Comment: Well, querying an array `b` by the indices stored in another array `a` is straightforward: `b[a]`. At this stage, I think, if you have further questions I suggest asking them in separate questions to avoid these comments becoming to convoluted.